# How to deal with timeout in currency conversion service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timeout

I just created this little currency converter for my Rails 4 app:

```
module Currency

  def self.get_exchange_rate(from_curr = "EUR", to_curr = "USD")   
    if from_curr == to_curr
      result = 1
    else
      begin
        amount = 1
        url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=#{amount}&from=#{from_curr}&to=#{to_curr}"
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
        result_span = doc.css('span.bld').text    
        result = result_span.tr('^0-9.', '')
      rescue => e
        puts e
        result = 1
      end
    end
    result
  end

end
```

I haven't done this a lot, so my question would be: How can I deal with the (unlikely) event that Google Currency times out or is not available for some reason?

In that case I would like my `result` to be `1`. How can this be achieved?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why is this a Nokogiri question?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply rescue any error that Nokogiri might raise (or OpenURI) like so:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def currency(a)
  Nokogiri::HTML(open(a))
rescue => e
  puts e
  1 # default value when error is raised
end

puts currency('https://www.somedomainthatdoesntexist.com')
```

That will print the backtrace of the error and then return the number 1

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
1
```

Answer (score 2):

For a custom timeout actions you can use `Timeout` module
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Answer (score 0):

It'd be worth looking at this answer to see how to get nokogiri to timeout : [Adjusting timeouts for Nokogiri connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498653/adjusting-timeouts-for-nokogiri-connections)

The question makes use of the [`timeout` module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) which is an option but I think it is better to get the connection to time out as per the accepted answer.

All that will mean that you'll get a `Timeout::Error` exception raised if the call times out which you then need to handle:

```
begin
  doc = ... use nokogiri ...
  result_span = doc.css('span.bld').text    
  result = result_span.tr('^0-9.', '')
rescue Timeout::Error
  result = 1
end
result
```

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't have timeouts, but OpenURI does.  Nokogiri might have parse errors, especially if that google page's css or html changes.

Comment: Yep, I know that nokogiri doesn't which is why I linked to the question about adjusting timeouts for Nokogiri connections. I then go on to explain that once you've connected to nokogiri in a way that *will* timeout that you can rescue the timeout error.

Comment: OK, not sure if I can follow you guys. I updated my initial post with the new version. It is meant to catch *any* error that might come up (including timeouts and css changes) and then set the result to `1`. Do you think it is going to work? (I don't know how to test this because there haven't been any errors in Google's conversion service so far.)