# Net::HTTP get timeout in Ruby

Tags: ruby, net-http

How can I set a larger timeout in net/http?
What I'm doing is this:

```
rta = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get(URI(url)))
```

I've tried:

```
uri = URI(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.open_timeout = 5* 60
http.read_timeout = 5* 60
rta = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get(URI(url)))
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe overwrite the initializer for Net::HTTP?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229194/ruby-nethttp-time-out

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it probably isn't working because you're making your `get` call on the Class instead of the instance you created.  Try changing that last line to:

```
rta = JSON.parse(http.get(URI(url)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use OpenURI :

```
require 'open-uri'
open(url, :read_timeout => 5 * 60) do |file|
  rta = JSON.parse file
  # ...
end
```