# Set read_timeout for the service call in Ruby Net::HTTP.start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to override the default timeout for the service call in my ruby code.
I open connection as under.

```
res = Net::HTTP.start(@@task_url.host, @@task_url.port) do |http|
    http.get("/tasks/#{task_id}")
end
```

I tried to set the read_timeout time as under but then I got the NoMethodError exception in my code.

```
res = Net::HTTP.start(@@task_url.host, @@task_url.port)
res.read_timeout = 10
res do |http|
    http.get("/tasks/#{task_id}")
end
```

Suggest me how should I set the read_timeout. And I am looking to set the read_timeout somewhere globally so that I can use that timeout for all my service call through Net::HTTPP.start()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Net::HTTP time out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229194/ruby-nethttp-time-out) also with HTTP.start, also set `read_timeout`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you use **Ruby 1.8** you have to use `Net::HTTP.new`:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
http.read_timeout = 10

response = http.get("/")    
# or intead of above line if you need block
# http.start do
#   response = http.get("/")
# end
```

If you look at the [source code](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-start) of `Net::HTTP.start`, you will see that `::start` is just calling `::new` with `#start` method:

```
# File net/http.rb, line 439
def HTTP.start(address, port = nil, p_addr = nil, p_port = nil, p_user = nil, p_pass = nil, &block) # :yield: +http+
  new(address, port, p_addr, p_port, p_user, p_pass).start(&block)
end
```

---

**>= Ruby 1.9**

You can set read_timeout in [opt argument](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-start):
`start(address, ..., opt, &block)`

like this:

```
res = Net::HTTP.start(host, port, :read_timeout => 10)
```

Comment: Can you post somewhere (gist.github.com) piece of code you're trying?

Comment: Try `irb`, just `require "net/http"; res = Net::HTTP.start(your_host, your_port, :read_timeout => 10)` if it works.

Comment: actually i think signature expects other values to be passed in the method as well. So will not try by passing other parameters as nul

Comment: Yes try it with other params with nil, but it's strange, because it works for me without problem.

Comment: Running in irb gives the same TypeError cannot convert hash to string

Comment: what are you running exactly ? I am getting wrong number of arguments (7 for 6)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5065172 I'm using `:open_timeout` for testing with `host="google.com"` and `port=81`.

Comment: what is you version of ruby? mine is ruby 1.8.7 . Same error came with your example also

Comment: Ofc, versions ;) [Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-start) for 1.8.7 is without **opt** arg.

Comment: how to do it in 1.8.7 ? any idea ?

Comment: i also tried doing it like this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f6bd9db4b26a6359510f but it showed me that no such method.

Comment: @manyu There's not any reason to use `Net::HTTP.start` over `Net::HTTP.new` because `::start` is only wrapper for `::new`, check the source.

Comment: Thanks A.D. I used new instead of start. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html) from `OpenURI`. This method has a `:read_timeout` option. I don't know how to set the option globally, but you can wrap it inside a custom function that sets this option.

```
require 'open-uri'
module NetCustom

  def open_url(url, &task)
     open(url, :read_timeout => 20) do |file|
       yield file.read
     end
  end

end
```

Usage:

```
class Foo
  include NetCustom

  def bar
    open_url('http://example.org/tasks/') do |content|
      # Handle page text content
    end
  end
end
```